# Tell users to right click on the map (As call to action)

Tags: user-behavior

I'm developing a web service where users can put their goods directly on the map.

I'm having a hard time to tell users to right click to add their goods on the map

This is the solution I opted for addressing my problem, but I'm not very satisfied...

You can try it live on https://neargood.com
can you tell me a better way to do it ?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: I think I broke it... http://i.imgur.com/9xius4z.png

Comment: That's a bug I'm aware of it. if you reload the page (F5) it'll work :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### It's because you're using an antipattern

- Right clicking is typically used to bring up contextual menus. It can be used to do other things, but that will not be intuitive because you have to overcome your users' learned behavior.
- Right clicking also presents some challenges for systems where there is no right-button on a mouse.

#### You can still use the right click, but the modern approach is to provide another primary interface

Here are some modern alternatives to forcing your users to right click:

[image: 1. provide a drag and drop tool, or 2. click a 'new' button and then cursor changes to a selector to drop a notice at a location]

Comment: Hello, and thank you so much for your input.

For the alternatives, do you mean an overlay and a message ?

Comment: @AymaneShuichi both suggestions can work with or without an overlay.  In both designs, the user is providing positive affirmation of intent (either by clicking or dragging), so you don't need an overlay to provide additional context, but if it helps the user get the job done better then go for it